# A lot of "undefined reference" errors

Tags: interrupt

I'm trying to create a program for my robot, but something is not right.
Here's the code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Tone.h>
#include <Wire.h>   // standardowa biblioteka Arduino
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h> // dolaczenie pobranej biblioteki I2C dla LCD

//Enums:
enum Dir
{
  forward = 1,
  backward = 2,
  left = 3,
  right = 4
};

enum State
{
    movingForward = 1,
    movingBack = 2,
    turningLeft = 3,
    turningRight = 4,
    doingNothing = 5,
    readyToMove = 6 //Potrzebne?
};

enum SpeedState
{
  slowingDown = 1,
  maxSpeed = 2,
  accelerating = 3,
  notMoving = 4
};


//Classes:
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd1(0x27, 20, 4);

//Base class for devices
class Device
{
    public:
        virtual void Init() = 0;
};

//STEPPER::
class StepMotor: public Device
{
    public:    
        int motorPin;
        int dirPin;
        int sleepPin;

        void Init ( void )
        {     
            pinMode(motorPin, OUTPUT);
            pinMode(dirPin, OUTPUT);
            pinMode(sleepPin, OUTPUT);

            toneObject.begin(motorPin);
        }

        void SetSpeed ( int speed )
        {
          toneObject.play(speed);
        }

    private:
      Tone toneObject;            
};

//VARIABLES:
int a = 1; //przyspieszenie (przyrost prędkości i jej ubytek przy hamowaniu
int s_accelerating = 1; //droga przyspieszania [mm]
int s_braking = 1;  //droga hamowania [mm]


class Robot
{
    public:
        static float x;
        static float y;
        static float t;
        static State state;
        static SpeedState speedState;
        static int currentSpeed;
};

class MoveOrder
{
  public:
    static Dir direction;
    static int distance;
    static int speed;
    static int distanceRemaining;
    static int distanceMade;    
};


//FUNCTIONS:
void SetInterrupt ( void )
{
    noInterrupts();           // disable all interrupts
    TCCR5A = 0;
    TCCR5B = 0;
    TCNT5  = 0;
    OCR5A = 310;            // compare match register 16MHz/256/2Hz   400 okolo 6.4ms  380-6.1ms 300-4.9ms
    TCCR5B |= (1 << WGM12);   // CTC mode
    TCCR5B |= (1 << CS12);    // 256 prescaler
    TIMSK5 |= (1 << OCIE1A);  // enable timer compare interrupt
    interrupts();             // enable all interrupts
}

void SetSpeed ( int speedValue )
{
   //currently empty
}


void setup() 
{   
    SetInterrupt();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}

ISR(TIMER5_COMPA_vect)
{
    if (Robot::state != doingNothing)
    {
        if (Robot::state == movingForward || Robot::state == movingBack )
        {
          if (MoveOrder::distanceMade < s_accelerating)
            {

                Robot::currentSpeed += a;

                SetSpeed(4);

            }
        }     
    }  
}
```

Compilation returns this:

```
Arduino:1.6.10 (Windows 10), Płytka:"Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560, ATmega2560 (Mega 2560)"

C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccU9OfJk.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `__vector_21':

ccU9OfJk.ltrans0.o:(.text+0x812): undefined reference to `Robot::state'

ccU9OfJk.ltrans0.o:(.text+0x816): undefined reference to `Robot::state'

C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccU9OfJk.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `__vector_47':

ccU9OfJk.ltrans0.o:(.text+0x820): undefined reference to `MoveOrder::distanceMade'

ccU9OfJk.ltrans0.o:(.text+0x824): undefined reference to `MoveOrder::distanceMade'

ccU9OfJk.ltrans0.o:(.text+0x82e): undefined reference to `Robot::currentSpeed'

ccU9OfJk.ltrans0.o:(.text+0x832): undefined reference to `Robot::currentSpeed'

ccU9OfJk.ltrans0.o:(.text+0x838): undefined reference to `Robot::currentSpeed'

ccU9OfJk.ltrans0.o:(.text+0x83c): undefined reference to `Robot::currentSpeed'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

exit status 1
```

I noticed that when I comment these lines:

```
        Robot::currentSpeed += a;

        SetSpeed(4);
```

errors are gone. Why?

Comment: Check the C++ syntax definition for static member data. They have to be defined; e.g. State Robot::state = initState;

Comment: "errors are gone" Because now the compiler isn't generating any code for anything, so there are no references to not find.

Comment: Just as a tip, when you see an error in a file ending in `.o` like this: `ccU9OfJk.ltrans0.o` - that is a *linker* error, not a *compiler* error. In other words, the syntax is OK, but you are missing something which the linker is trying to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have only *declared* the class static variables; you never *defined* them.  For the `Robot` class, you must have:

```
class Robot
{
    public:
         ...
};

float      Robot::x;
float      Robot::y;
float      Robot::t;
State      Robot::state = doingNothing;
SpeedState Robot::speedState = notMoving;
int        Robot::currentSpeed;

void setup()
{
```

Ditto for other classes.  (Dangit, Mikael!  :) )

Comment: It's weird. In C# I wouldn't have to do it I guess.